# Routing App Coverage File

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I've recently submitted my game to the App Store.  It has recently been approved and is "Processing for the App Store".  When I click on my application, it says "Routing App Coverage File".  Just curious on what this means exactly?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The "Routing App Coverage File" is a GeoJSON file which describes the coverage area for a public transit routing application (to be used with iOS 6 Maps). The iTunes Connect Developers Guide says:

> Routing app coverage files are `.geojson` files which specify the geographic regions supported by your app. The file can have only one MultiPolygon element. MultiPolygon elements consist of at least one Polygon. Polygons contain at least four coordinate points. Polygon start and end coordinate points must be the same.

Of course if your app doesn't have anything to do with public transit routing, you can ignore this.

Comment: In case that you need to see the problem with the file you can check the problem using this site: [GeoJSONLint](http://www.geojsonlint.com/)

Also, you can also see [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW7) on the **Listing 7-2 A sample GeoJSON file** label