# Why App store not accepting my routing app coverage file?

Tags: ios

After I  upload the Aus.geojson file (routing app coverage file) I get the following error:
JSON file you uploaded was invalid. The file must contain only one element of type multipolygon. Below is the JSON file which i was submitting and in which I see only one multipolygon element. Why I am getting the error?

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "Australia" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 145.397978, -40.792549 ], [ 146.364121, -41.137695 ], [ 146.908584, -41.000546 ], [ 147.689259, -40.808258 ], [ 148.289068, -40.875438 ], [ 148.359865, -42.062445 ], [ 148.017301, -42.407024 ], [ 147.914052, -43.211522 ], [ 147.564564, -42.937689 ], [ 146.870343, -43.634597 ], [ 146.663327, -43.580854 ], [ 146.048378, -43.549745 ], [ 145.431930, -42.693776 ], [ 145.295090, -42.033610 ], [ 144.718071, -41.162552 ], [ 144.743755, -40.703975 ], [ 145.397978, -40.792549 ] ] ], [ [ [ 143.561811, -13.763656 ], [ 143.922099, -14.548311 ], [ 144.563714, -14.171176 ], [ 144.894908, -14.594458 ], [ 145.374724, -14.984976 ], [ 145.271991, -15.428205 ], [ 145.485260, -16.285672 ], [ 145.637033, -16.784918 ], [ 145.888904, -16.906926 ], [ 146.160309, -17.761655 ], [ 146.063674, -18.280073 ], [ 146.387478, -18.958274 ], [ 147.471082, -19.480723 ], [ 148.177602, -19.955939 ], [ 148.848414, -20.391210 ], [ 148.717465, -20.633469 ], [ 149.289420, -21.260511 ], [ 149.678337, -22.342512 ], [ 150.077382, -22.122784 ], [ 150.482939, -22.556142 ], [ 150.727265, -22.402405 ], [ 150.899554, -23.462237 ], [ 151.609175, -24.076256 ], [ 152.073540, -24.457887 ], [ 152.855197, -25.267501 ], [ 153.136162, -26.071173 ], [ 153.161949, -26.641319 ], [ 153.092909, -27.260300 ], [ 153.569469, -28.110067 ], [ 153.512108, -28.995077 ], [ 153.339095, -29.458202 ], [ 153.069241, -30.350240 ], [ 153.089602, -30.923642 ], [ 152.891578, -31.640446 ], [ 152.450002, -32.550003 ], [ 151.709117, -33.041342 ], [ 151.343972, -33.816023 ], [ 151.010555, -34.310360 ], [ 150.714139, -35.173460 ], [ 150.328220, -35.671879 ], [ 150.075212, -36.420206 ], [ 149.946124, -37.109052 ], [ 149.997284, -37.425261 ], [ 149.423882, -37.772681 ], [ 148.304622, -37.809061 ], [ 147.381733, -38.219217 ], [ 146.922123, -38.606532 ], [ 146.317922, -39.035757 ], [ 145.489652, -38.593768 ], [ 144.876976, -38.417448 ], [ 145.032212, -37.896188 ], [ 144.485682, -38.085324 ], [ 143.609974, -38.809465 ], [ 142.745427, -38.538268 ], [ 142.178330, -38.380034 ], [ 141.606582, -38.308514 ], [ 140.638579, -38.019333 ], [ 139.992158, -37.402936 ], [ 139.806588, -36.643603 ], [ 139.574148, -36.138362 ], [ 139.082808, -35.732754 ], [ 138.120748, -35.612296 ], [ 138.449462, -35.127261 ], [ 138.207564, -34.384723 ], [ 137.719170, -35.076825 ], [ 136.829406, -35.260535 ], [ 137.352371, -34.707339 ], [ 137.503886, -34.130268 ], [ 137.890116, -33.640479 ], [ 137.810328, -32.900007 ], [ 136.996837, -33.752771 ], [ 136.372069, -34.094766 ], [ 135.989043, -34.890118 ], [ 135.208213, -34.478670 ], [ 135.239218, -33.947953 ], [ 134.613417, -33.222778 ], [ 134.085904, -32.848072 ], [ 134.273903, -32.617234 ], [ 132.990777, -32.011224 ], [ 132.288081, -31.982647 ], [ 131.326331, -31.495803 ], [ 129.535794, -31.590423 ], [ 128.240938, -31.948489 ], [ 127.102867, -32.282267 ], [ 126.148714, -32.215966 ], [ 125.088623, -32.728751 ], [ 124.221648, -32.959487 ], [ 124.028947, -33.483847 ], [ 123.659667, -33.890179 ], [ 122.811036, -33.914467 ], [ 122.183064, -34.003402 ], [ 121.299191, -33.821036 ], [ 120.580268, -33.930177 ], [ 119.893695, -33.976065 ], [ 119.298899, -34.509366 ], [ 119.007341, -34.464149 ], [ 118.505718, -34.746819 ], [ 118.024972, -35.064733 ], [ 117.295507, -35.025459 ], [ 116.625109, -35.025097 ], [ 115.564347, -34.386428 ], [ 115.026809, -34.196517 ], [ 115.048616, -33.623425 ], [ 115.545123, -33.487258 ], [ 115.714674, -33.259572 ], [ 115.679379, -32.900369 ], [ 115.801645, -32.205062 ], [ 115.689611, -31.612437 ], [ 115.160909, -30.601594 ], [ 114.997043, -30.030725 ], [ 115.040038, -29.461095 ], [ 114.641974, -28.810231 ], [ 114.616498, -28.516399 ], [ 114.173579, -28.118077 ], [ 114.048884, -27.334765 ], [ 113.477498, -26.543134 ], [ 113.338953, -26.116545 ], [ 113.778358, -26.549025 ], [ 113.440962, -25.621278 ], [ 113.936901, -25.911235 ], [ 114.232852, -26.298446 ], [ 114.216161, -25.786281 ], [ 113.721255, -24.998939 ], [ 113.625344, -24.683971 ], [ 113.393523, -24.384764 ], [ 113.502044, -23.806350 ], [ 113.706993, -23.560215 ], [ 113.843418, -23.059987 ], [ 113.736552, -22.475475 ], [ 114.149756, -21.755881 ], [ 114.225307, -22.517488 ], [ 114.647762, -21.829520 ], [ 115.460167, -21.495173 ], [ 115.947373, -21.068688 ], [ 116.711615, -20.701682 ], [ 117.166316, -20.623599 ], [ 117.441545, -20.746899 ], [ 118.229559, -20.374208 ], [ 118.836085, -20.263311 ], [ 118.987807, -20.044203 ], [ 119.252494, -19.952942 ], [ 119.805225, -19.976506 ], [ 120.856220, -19.683708 ], [ 121.399856, -19.239756 ], [ 121.655138, -18.705318 ], [ 122.241665, -18.197649 ], [ 122.286624, -17.798603 ], [ 122.312772, -17.254967 ], [ 123.012574, -16.405200 ], [ 123.433789, -17.268558 ], [ 123.859345, -17.069035 ], [ 123.503242, -16.596506 ], [ 123.817073, -16.111316 ], [ 124.258287, -16.327944 ], [ 124.379726, -15.567060 ], [ 124.926153, -15.075100 ], [ 125.167275, -14.680396 ], [ 125.670087, -14.510070 ], [ 125.685796, -14.230656 ], [ 126.125149, -14.347341 ], [ 126.142823, -14.095987 ], [ 126.582589, -13.952791 ], [ 127.065867, -13.817968 ], [ 127.804633, -14.276906 ], [ 128.359690, -14.869170 ], [ 128.985543, -14.875991 ], [ 129.621473, -14.969784 ], [ 129.409600, -14.420670 ], [ 129.888641, -13.618703 ], [ 130.339466, -13.357376 ], [ 130.183506, -13.107520 ], [ 130.617795, -12.536392 ], [ 131.223495, -12.183649 ], [ 131.735091, -12.302453 ], [ 132.575298, -12.114041 ], [ 132.557212, -11.603012 ], [ 131.824698, -11.273782 ], [ 132.357224, -11.128519 ], [ 133.019561, -11.376411 ], [ 133.550846, -11.786515 ], [ 134.393068, -12.042365 ], [ 134.678632, -11.941183 ], [ 135.298491, -12.248606 ], [ 135.882693, -11.962267 ], [ 136.258381, -12.049342 ], [ 136.492475, -11.857209 ], [ 136.951620, -12.351959 ], [ 136.685125, -12.887223 ], [ 136.305407, -13.291230 ], [ 135.961758, -13.324509 ], [ 136.077617, -13.724278 ], [ 135.783836, -14.223989 ], [ 135.428664, -14.715432 ], [ 135.500184, -14.997741 ], [ 136.295175, -15.550265 ], [ 137.065360, -15.870762 ], [ 137.580471, -16.215082 ], [ 138.303217, -16.807604 ], [ 138.585164, -16.806622 ], [ 139.108543, -17.062679 ], [ 139.260575, -17.371601 ], [ 140.215245, -17.710805 ], [ 140.875463, -17.369069 ], [ 141.071110, -16.832047 ], [ 141.274095, -16.388870 ], [ 141.398222, -15.840532 ], [ 141.702183, -15.044921 ], [ 141.563380, -14.561333 ], [ 141.635520, -14.270395 ], [ 141.519869, -13.698078 ], [ 141.650920, -12.944688 ], [ 141.842691, -12.741548 ], [ 141.686990, -12.407614 ], [ 141.928629, -11.877466 ], [ 142.118488, -11.328042 ], [ 142.143706, -11.042737 ], [ 142.515260, -10.668186 ], [ 142.797310, -11.157355 ], [ 142.866763, -11.784707 ], [ 143.115947, -11.905630 ], [ 143.158632, -12.325656 ], [ 143.522124, -12.834358 ], [ 143.597158, -13.400422 ], [ 143.561811, -13.763656 ] ] ] ] } }

]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the start and end coordinates have to match:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573711/785716

Comment: Multipolygon consists of two polygons in above code and start and end coordinates of each polygons match.

Comment: My Apologies, I didn't see the split. It looks to me like each Polygon might be surrounded by too many square brackets. Try removing a set, see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is struggling to make this work, Please use [this](http://geojson.io/) to generate the `.geojson` file and change `type` to `MultiPolygon` and add polygon arrays to the coordinates object. After adding those polygons, your `.geojson` file should look as follows,

**Note the `[]` inside the `coordinates` and also your start coordinates and end coordinates should match**

[image]

Here is some working `.geojson` snippet.

```
{
  "type": "MultiPolygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        [
          3.33984375,
          46.49839225859763
        ],
        [
          15.732421875,
          46.49839225859763
        ],
        [
          15.732421875,
          55.7765730186677
        ],
        [
          3.33984375,
          55.7765730186677
        ],
        [
          3.33984375,
          46.49839225859763
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

Please refer to **Listing 7.2** of the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW7) for more info